# how to change blue Go key return key in ios keyboard on input tag in ionic

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework

In ios  tags in a  tag will change the "return" key to a blue "go" key. how can i disable this on input tag in ionic for ios

Comment: It seems like there is no easy way: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard/issues/54

Comment: This didn't help me much